# Get second without using time.second

Tags: python

new to python, lets say i have

```
t = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
```

how can I get only the second without using

```
t.second
```

nor

```
int(t[-2:])
```

Comment: What is `t.second` supposed to be? `t` is a string... there is no `second` attribute. And what is with the restriction?

Answer (score 1):

One way is with split:

```
t = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
seconds = int(t.split(':')[-1])
print(seconds) # prints 10
```

Another with a simple regex:

```
import re
t = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
seconds = int(re.search(r'(\d+)\Z',t).group(1))
print(seconds) # prints 10
```

Using arrow it can be done like this:

```
import arrow
t = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
seconds = int(arrow.get(t, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('ss'))
print(seconds) # prints 10
```

And similarly using datetime.strptime.strftime:

```
t = "2008-12-12 19:21:10"
seconds = int(datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%S'))
print(seconds) # prints 10
```

or more simply (if allowed):

```
seconds = datetime.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').second
print(seconds) # prints 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Or your old friend Regular Expressions:

```
import re
m = re.match("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})", t)
seconds = int(m.group(6))
```